# ActionFunction is working only with reRender="" and not with any value inside it

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, apexactionfunction

I am experiencing a strange behavior for the first time...

I have a actionFunction in my apex compoenent, which has reRender to some panel id. The panel doesnot reRender at all even though the method is successfully executed at the back end. If I make it empty reRender function and put an alert on complete, this works..

AM I MISSING Something?

```
<apex:actionFunction name="fetchRecords" action="{!refreshSubCaseRecords}" oncomplete="alert('123')" immediate="true" reRender="refreshPanel" />
```

Comment: do you actually need the immediate = true?

Comment: @brovasi just trying different attributes.. nothing working..

Comment: Can you post more of your page? You might need to use a hierarchy of IDs to indicate what to refresh.

Answer (score 2):

Wild guess (you still need to post more code) but rerender only applies to child elements and not the element itself.

For example if you rerender:

```
<apex:outputText id="output" rendered="{!condition}" value="text" />
```

it won't work.

But if you change it to(with output panel):

```
<apex:outputPanel id="output">
    <apex:outputText rendered="{!condition}" value="text" />
</apex:outputPanel>
```

presto bingo.

Answer (score 0):

May be your are reRendering a output panel which is having render condition 
so put a outputpanel outside that output panel and then rerender that parent outputpanel

Comment: Nopes.. I am aware of that.. I dont have any rendered action in the same panel..